# What kind of date format is this, and how do I parse it in SPSS?

Tags: date, datetime, parsing, spss

What kind of date format is `1037112:00:00.00`, and how do I parse it in SPSS into something recognizable?

For reference, here's a screenshot. We're dealing with V2 and V4 (and, to an extent, V3 and V5):
[image]

**Edit:** When I change the format of V2 in SPPS from *Date* to *Numeric*, the actual number of the highlighted cell is `3733603200`:

[image]

The file format from which I imported the data into SPSS is Excel — and although the date renders correctly in Excel (as "23-Apr"), I'm doubtful that Excel was the native format in which this data set was created. The data was exported from an online survey; I wish I had more information about it.

Here's the V2 column's values rendered in Excel (with the cells formatted as "General"):
[image]

Comment: (1) What format was the data imported from? (2) can you supply examples of the actual dates for some of your numbers?

Comment: The actual number of the first cell, for example, is 3733603200. The data was imported from an Excel file, which automatically parses it as "April 23" (using a "General" cell format), but I doubt that the data was natively created in Excel; it's originally from an online survey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates as a decimal number. The whole number part is the number of days since `1 Jan 1900`, while the fractional part is the fraction of a day since midnight (0.5 would be noon). If you were to format the cells to include the year, you’d find the highlighted cell converted to `23 Apr 2018 00:00:00` - perfect!

If you look at the raw number, it’s `3,733,603,200`. Divide this by `60` to convert seconds into minutes, then again by `60` to convert minutes into hours - and you get the exact number in your question: `1,037,112` hours, `00` minutes, and `00.0` seconds.

If you then divide this number by `24` to convert hours into days, you get (exactly) `43,213`. If you ask Excel to format a cell with this number as a full date, you’ll get the previous `23 Apr 2018` - there are 43,213 days from 1 Jan 1900 to 23 Apr 2018.

SPSS date variables are stored internally as the number of ***seconds*** since `14 Oct 1582 00:00:00`, so you’d (normally) have to do some complicated maths! Luckily, you simply need to add the number of days between the two “epochs” - `115,859` - but don’t forget to convert this to seconds! Multiply it by `24 * 60 * 60` first (`10,010,217,600`).

Note that V3 and V5 are NOT 24-hour time. Some are marked as “`am`”, so the `18` must be the date of the month, not the hours - also note the lack of colon!

---

<sub>I couldn’t help myself: I had to add this extra bit.</sub>

***Why*** did IBM choose such a weird start epoch? `14 Oct 1582` happens to be the first day of the (then) new Gregorian calendar, instituted by Pope Gregory II. The day before was `5 Oct 1582` - accounting for those missing days makes for some *horrible* mathematics, so IBM just avoided it.

The missing days were to make up for all the mistaken *extra* days they’d added in previous centuries for Leap Years that shouldn’t have been (those years that could divide by 100, but not 400).